# How to sort easily a XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, c, xml

I have the given XML:

```
<colors>
  <green>150</green>
  <red>18</red>
  <blue>920</blue>
  <orange>80</orange>
  <purple>77</purple>
</colors>
```

I need to read the XML file and after that sorting it to use it as an C Header File.

For example:

```
#define orange        80             // <orange>
#define red           18            // <red>
```

It should be possible to change the order of the XML tags.

```
private void TranslateXmlToC(String path)   
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);

    XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//colors");

    Console.WriteLine(list.Item(0).InnerXml);
}
```

This code shows all tags and data right but now I want to change the order.

Comment: Then why the C# tag?

Comment: Using C# for this Tool

Comment: You want to read the xml file, in c#, then sort it, in c# to export it too a c header, correct? what have you tried so far? For example how do you read the xml? or how do you write a c header?

Comment: Changed my code in the question

Comment: Thank you, what do you see in the console now? I expect :<green>150</green> but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why not parse out the name-value pairs, sort them and then write out the header. Re-organising the XML (unless you expect to update the file) just makes for more work.

Comment: Actually the many down votes seem to be quite unfair. This is a new user... The question is not that unclear, that people have to tear it into pieces... +1 from my side and a reopen vote.

Comment: If you want to work with XML in C# and avoid headaches, you might want to look into [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387061.aspx). [LINQ (to objects)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397926.aspx) is also incredibly helpful for any kind of list(-like) manipulation, like sorting for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<colors>" + 
            "<green>150</green>" +
            "<red>18</red>" + 
            "<blue>920</blue>" +
            "<orange>80</orange>" +
            "<purple>77</purple>" +
            "</colors>");

var lst = new Dictionary<string,int>();
foreach (XmlNode n in xml["colors"].ChildNodes)
    lst.Add(n.Name, int.Parse(n.InnerText));

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> n in lst.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value))
    sb.AppendFormat("#define {0}   {1}    // <{0}>\n", n.Key, n.Value);

string result = sb.ToString();
```

The result (you might use C# string padding):

```
#define red   18    // <red>
#define purple   77    // <purple>
#define orange   80    // <orange>
#define green   150    // <green>
#define blue   920    // <blue>
```

Comment: It might also be nice to add the creation of the c header file via: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path+"\\headerFile.h", sb);`

Comment: Or: `string.Join("\n", XDocument.Load(path).Element("colors").Elements().OrderBy(e => int.Parse(e.Value)).Select(e => string.Format("#define {0}   {1}    // <{0}>", e.Name, e.Value)))`

Comment: @Corak, Let this be a working example in an own answer and I will definitely vote it up!

Comment: This works like a charm!

Comment: @rejoin14, Hi happy that I could help you. Welcome on SO! This was a harsh introduction with so many down votes. The "SO police" is sometimes much to fast...

Comment: @Shnugo - Well, the question is locked. But there wouldn't be much to add anyway. As I already stated in my other comment, [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387061.aspx) is incredibly power-, use-, and helpful for working with sequences of any kind. And XML is basically a sequence of potentially nested (sequences of) elements. -- Btw. the provided code was more "for fun", as it lacks readability. But another great thing about LINQ is, that it's easy to separate. `var document = XDocument.Load(path); var colorsElement = document.Element("colors");` and so on.

Comment: @Corak, Your answer is very nice and would deserver some reputation. To do you a favor I just visited your profile and voted another answer up :-)

Comment: @Corak, would you please do me a favor too? Please tick my comment under the OP (refering unfair down votes)  to get it in the visible area... Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could use XPath for C# to get all the nodes/text you need (http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/using-xpath-with-the-xmldocument-class/). With XPath you can select all nodes under 'colors' for example.

Afterwards, you could sort them and then obviously create the according file and write it in the syntax you need.